# Scrapy spider not accessing the link i want to

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Some days ago i tried adding some functionality to my spider's parser.
My objective is to scrape some amazon pages, problem is that i need to make the parser work differently for each product i want to search.
For example, if i want to search for laptops, my parser works in a way but if i search for shoes, it works differently. I did it this way:

```
def start_requests(self):

    keyword_callback = {

        'Laptop' : self.parse_item
    }


    txtfile = open('productosABuscar.txt', 'r')

    keywords = txtfile.readlines()

    txtfile.close()

    for keyword in keywords:


        yield Request(self.search_url.format(keyword), callback = keyword_callback[keyword])
```

The issue im encountering here is that, when i do the yield request, my spider is not "searching" the keyword and entering the link, so the parser only gets 1 link and no data.

If any extra information is needed be sure to ask!

Edit: Adding extra information

```
class PrototipoAmazonV1Spider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'spiderProtAmazon'

    #Dominio permitido
    allowed_domain = ['www.amazon.com']

    search_url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?field-keywords={}'

    rules = {

    #Todos los elementos en la pagina
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =(), restrict_xpaths = ('//*[contains(@class, "s-access-detail-page")]') ), 
                            callback = 'parse_item', follow = False)
}


#Previous start request goes here

def parse_item(self, response):

    amz_item = Prototipoamazonv1Item()

    #info de producto
    amz_item['nombreProducto'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[contains(@id, "productTitle")]/text())').extract()

    amz_item['urlProducto'] = response.request.url

    yield amz_item
```

I'm currently using 1 parser while I try out if this works. My idea is to have different parsers for each keyword.

When running this program, the only data i get is, from the 'urlProducto'

'urlProducto' = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?field-keywords=Laptop'

Problem is that my spider is not getting "inside" each product for retrieving the data. If i force the previous url (urlProducto) as the starting one, it works just fine.

Comment: Can you show the whole spider and log?, question isn't clear

Comment: Edited the question!

Comment: You shouldn't access to detail of every item? e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Apple-MacBook-13-inch-display-dual-core/dp/B07JZYWCV1/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1545668315&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=Laptop&psc=1

Comment: Yeah, i want to access every item and retrieve some information from each one of them. Thing is that, with what i have right now (not forcing the urls) my spider is not accessing each one of the products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy doesn't automatically parse the url to again crawl either you need to pass link extractor Rule or need to get the next url from source and then pass it to another method

In Your case  You need to get the href of this anchor tag of each item then Create a scrapy Request to parse the content in that page.

```
def parse_item(self, response):
     for item in response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'s-result-item')]"):
          url = //search for the detail page url
          yield Scrapy.Request(url,self.parse_detail)

def parse_detail(self, response):
     //here you need to define what you want to get from detail page
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, the //div[contains(@class,'s-result-item')] is not returning any data from the amazon site. What is supposed to go in that response, every item in a product page?, for example, once you are inside a category, the xpath ('//*[contains(@class, "s-access-detail-page")]')

Comment: i think Amazon is JavaScript based web application so alone with scrapy you won't able to crawl, you need to use scrapy-splash along with it. And your second question i guess you are asking about the response of parse_detail method

Comment: If it's the case then yes you need to define items that you want to get from the details page of a product.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome, and to know exact css of each element you can use selectorgadget.com